# Render a component ONLY WHEN the image inside the component successfully loads

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How can I delay the rendering of "My favorite image" (and the rest of the component) until the image successfully loads, which takes some time.

This is what I have attempted so far:

```
function ProjectCardView(props) {

    const [isImageLoaded, setIsImageLoaded] = useState(false)
    let imgTag = <img onLoad={() => {setIsImageLoaded(true)}} src={props.imgSrc}/>

    if (!isImageLoaded) {
        return <div></div>
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1> My favorite image </h1>
            {imgTag}
            
        </div>
    )
}
```

This issue with this attempt is that the whole component never appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are rendering the component with the condition in this code.

```
if (!isImageLoaded) {
  return <div></div>
}
```

This will execute an empty `div` on the page. So you won't find anything on UI not even the `img` tag also. Your need to render the image first then only your state variables will get updated.

Check this sandbox. I am printing `loading` when the image is loading and `loaded` when it's done. Just update your conditions based on your image load time.

[image: Edit mystifying-almeida-0lep2c]

Comment: Would the imgTag variable not run the onLoad callback and trigger a re-render?

i.e 1. Callback runs 2. First render returns an empty div because isImageLoaded=False 3. The callback finishes and triggers another render, with isImageLoaded = True this time

Comment: Ohhhh! I see. My onLoad callback never runs because I never render the image tag itself. Changing the "return <div></div>" line to "return imgTag" fixed it